# Python API : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Tags: python, json, api, urldecode

I'm getting the error in the title (see full traceback below) with this code. I'm authenticating using a site API and then trying to post a JSON object to create a campaign, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm a beginner, so your criticism about my code would be welcome too. This is the first time I'm dealing with an API

```
import requests
import json

client_key = r'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = r'yyyyyyyyy'

#Password authentication
authRequest = requests.post("https://backstage.site.com/backstage/oauth/token?client_id="+ client_key +"&client_secret="+ client_secret)

data = {
    "name": "Demo Campaign",
    "branding_text": "Pizza",
    "cpc": 0.25,
    "spending_limit": 1000,
    "spending_limit_model": "MONTHLY"
}

token = 'Bearer ' + authRequest.json()['access_token']
print(token)
url = "https://backstage.site.com/backstage/api/1.0/xxxxx/campaigns/"

headers = {
    'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    }

resp = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8','Authorization':"'" + token + "'"})

print(resp.json())
```

Traceback

```
C:\Users\home\VisualCodeProjects>^Zcd c:\Users\home\VisualCodeProjects && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && python c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py 57290 e:\Dropbox2\Dropbox\Ubot\Ubot\Python\Taboola-API-playground.py "
C:\Users\home\VisualCodeProjects>cd c:\Users\home\VisualCodeProjects && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && python c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py 57426 e:\Dropbox2\Dropbox\Ubot\Ubot\Python\Taboola-API-playground.py "
Bearer CXwJAAAAAAAAEVDsAhZjgzY2IyZjU0YzM0Zjk1MmYyNDRiZmU0Njg4OTAyZEAC::xxxxx::yyyyyy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 118, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, '', '', run_as)
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_local.py", line 79, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_local.py", line 140, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1751, in main
    debugger.connect(host, port)
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1107, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1114, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\Users\home\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.9.2\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "e:\Dropbox2\Dropbox\Ubot\Ubot\Python\Taboola-API-playground.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(resp.json())
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: *data=json.dumps(data) * 
I think the json.dumps is causing the issue if im not mistaken. json.dumps converts to a string in a valid json format, but its still a string. is that the issue?

Comment: I don't think, because the server requests a valid JSON object.

Comment: give it a shot with just data. a valid json object should be a json/dictionary, and not a string. (and let me know if it works or not, would love to hear)

Comment: I've already tried and it returns the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the server does not return a valid JSON. Try examaning the response's code and `.text` to see if your request succeeded and what the server responded with.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "Try examaning the response's code and .text to see if your request succeeded and what the server responded with." As I asid, I'm pretty new to Python and there is a lot that I have to learn, Thx

Comment: print(resp.json()) to resp.text() or something of that sort. @CreekBarbara

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'str' object is not callable

Comment: resp.text then seems to be the way to go. @CreekBarbara

Comment: But the print is only to display the server response. and with text() I receive the error above and the script stops. And btw, my campaign is not created on the site.

Comment: try the .text without the brackets and see what happens. @CreekBarbara

Comment: You were right. Now it tells me <UnauthorizedException><error>unauthorized</error><error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description></UnauthorizedException>. Does this means the I'm using password authentication, should I use the implicite grant?

Comment: Your last question is specific to the API you are using. Please refer to its documentation and/or support.